# How to sort the data based on preference array using sql query in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, sequelize.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0toKv.png)
// Code

```
    regionFilter={
        "India":["India","Pakistan","Srilanka"],
        "America":["India","America","UK","Malaysia"],
        "Japan":["Japan","China","Korea"],
        "Russia":["Russia","Korea","China"],
        "HongKong":["HongoKong","Switzerland","Singapore"]
    }
    filterUser = catchAsyncError(async(req,res,next)=>{
        const {gender,age,country} = req.body; 
        User.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    {"gender":gender},
                    {"country":{
                        [Op.in]:this.regionFilter[country]
                        }
                    },
                    {"age":{
                        [Op.between]:[age-10,age+10]
                    }
                }]
            },
            attributes: ['userId','name','country','gender','age']
        }).then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
        })
    })
}
```

Here i want data to be sorted based on regionFilter array
EX if req.body contains Country as India then the user comes sorted based on the regionFilter[India] column like firstly Indian users come after that Pakistan and then Sri Lanka. How to do this thing in SQL query?

I am not getting the solution so i expect it from someone ho we need to order by based on some preference array in SQL sequelize.

Comment: pleas add code as text..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL ORDER BY you need to build looks something like:

```sql
ORDER BY FIELD(`country`, 'India', 'Pakistan', 'Srilanka')
```

The [FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.

I am not familiar with Sequelize but I believe you can achieve this by passing the RAW SQL to the order parameter:

```
User.findAll({
    where: { ... },
    attributes: ['userId','name','country','gender','age'],
    order: sequelize.literal("FIELD(`country`, '" + this.regionFilter[country].join("', '") + "')")
})
```